# Ionic 3 tabs navigation not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

After successfully creating an ionic 3 tabs project I added Login page which consist of one button (Login with Google) I want to redirect user to new Page - Tabs page. Here is the code:

```
    if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider).then(result => {
    let token = result.credential.accessToken;
    let user = result.user;
    console.log(token, user);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);

  });
```

The Tabs Page loads without problem but my navigation at the bottom is not working correctly. The Tabs are not highlighted as they should be.

Comment: If the tabs page loads without a problem, but the tab navigation is not working correctly, why are you showing us the part of your code that definitely does work? What logic do you have in TabsPage? Whats your TabsPage template(html) look like?

Comment: To give more context. The tabs are just plain pages, I did not edit them at all. The template is exactly as it is when you run ionic start appname tabs.